# 3-4 days in Korea

Tags: south-korea

I am going to a business conference in Korea in July. I've managed to prolong my stay by 3-4 days (can't stay longer because I have another meeting in Europe). The event is in Seoul. What are "must see" things in Korea (within my short period staying there)? I tried asking a friend, but she only mentioned city names...

Should I stay in Seoul, or is it possible to head somewhere else in that short period of time?

I have never been to Asia before. I am not that into way too touristy things BTW. I am aware that the list might be long, but I just want to know the "must sees" (like Greece - Acropolis, Paris - Eiffel tower, Peru - Machu Picchu...)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really enjoyed seeing [Changdeok Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changdeokgung) (in Seoul) while I was there. I would definitely put that on the must-see list. I'm sure Gyeongbok Palace would also be great to see, but I didn't get to see it when I was there (I was only there on a 10 hour layover.)

At least being from the U.S., it was also interesting just driving around the city and seeing high-rise apartment complexes everywhere you look. We don't have any cities in the U.S. that are nearly as population-dense (or as populated at all) as Seoul. And going there on the back end of a 2-week trip to the Philippines, it was also nice to see sane traffic and actual highways. :)

As far as traveling out of Seoul is concerned, South Korea is quite small (at least by my U.S. standards of distance,) so I doubt it would be difficult to visit another city for a day if you wanted to. The farthest part of mainland South Korea is only about 300 km from Incheon International Airport. Having said that, there's plenty to see in the greater Seoul area that you could probably spend 3-4 days just there and not see everything you want to see.